# how to do many2one domain filter?

Tags: python, odoo

i have one calendar.event inherited module there i wanted to make domain filter based on location i.e Asset location again 'asset_catg_id' will filter from 'asset_catg_id' its working fine

from openerp.osv import fields, osv # its cal.event class inherited

```
class calendar_event(osv.osv):

    _inherit = "calendar.event"
    _rec_name = 'number'

    _columns = {
            'number' : fields.char('Meeting ID',readonly=1),
            #'place' : fields.many2one('stock.location','Substation Location',),

            'place' : fields.many2one('asset.parentlocation','Substation Location',),
            #'location' : fields.selection(STATUS_SELECTION,'Location',  default='Board A'),
            'asset_catg_id' : fields.many2one('asset.catg', 'Asset Catg Selection',),
             'area_id' : fields.many2one('asset.name','Asset Name Selection', domain="[('asset_catg_id', '=', asset_catg_id)]", select=True, required=True),
            'assetmodelid_add' : fields.many2many('agile.portfolio1','agile_portfolio1_rel','super_id','agile_portfolio1_id','Asset Model Code',),
            'folio_num' : fields.many2many('asset.asset','asset_asset_rel','super_id','asset_asset_id','Folio Num',),
            #'folio_num' : fields.related('folio_num','folio_num',string='Folio Num',relation='asset.asset', type='many2one')   
            }

    _defaults = {
                'number' : lambda self,cr,uid,context={}:self.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr,uid,'calendar.event'),
                }


class asset_asset(osv.osv): #asset inherited
    _inherit = "asset.asset"
    #_name = "asset_asset"
    _rec_name= "folio_num"
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Asset Name', size=64),
        'asset_catg_id' : fields.many2one('asset.catg', 'Asset Catg Selection',select=True, required=True),
               'area_id' : fields.many2one('asset.name', 'Asset Name Selection', domain="[('asset_catg_id', '=', asset_catg_id)]", select=True, required=True),
        'assetmodelid_add' : fields.many2one('agile.portfolio1','Asset Model Code',domain="[('area_id', '=', area_id)]",),
        'folio_num' : fields.char('Folio No', readonly=1),
        'asse_line':fields.one2many('asset.line','emp_id','Name Plate'),
        'asse_line2':fields.one2many('asset.part','emp_id1','Parts'),
               # 'assed_modelid':fields.many2one('agile.portfolio1','Asset Model ID',select=True, required=True),
        'quantity': fields.char('Quantity',size=64),
        'uom': fields.char('Uinit of Measure',size=64),
        'model_no' : fields.char('Model', size=64),
        'place': fields.many2one('asset.parentlocation', 'Location'),
        #'asset_id':fields.many2one('agile.portfolio','Asset ID'),

    }
class asset_parentlocation(osv.osv):
    _name="asset.parentlocation"
    _rec_name="location_name"
    _columns = {
        'location_name' : fields.char('Asset Location', required=True),
        'parent_location' : fields.many2one('asset.parentlocation','Parent Location'),}

    def name_get(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        if context is None:
            context = {}
        if not ids:
            return []
        reads = self.read(cr, uid, ids, ['location_name','parent_location'], context=context)
        res = []
        for record in reads:
            name = record['location_name']
            if record['parent_location']:enter code here
                name = record['parent_location'][1]+' / '+name
            res.append((record['id'], name))
        return res
```

Comment: Not getting idea what you want to do, please clarify it with field and expected result.

Comment: i have created one inherit class for asset.asset theri i have created som fields 'asset_catg_id','area_id' etc ..  i will enter some data here . then this fields wiil be inherited to calendar.evemt class . when i select 'place'; in next field 'asset_catg_id'  we have to get only related to that place .

Comment: _inherit = "calendar.event" is calendar module _inherit = "asset.asst" is asset.. i want domain filter concept .. intially had done by  'asset_catg_id'  this are working fine but now i have added one more field so am gettin difficulties here so need some idea